# check OTP before registration in Django Rest Auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django Rest Auth plugin for registration and login in Django Rest Framework. I want to check OTP (unique key) while user registration.
We are sending OTP based on Mobile number to users. Django checks OTP after registration. I want to set those condition before registration. 
If conditions are true then registration should be done.

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    otp_no = forms.CharField(label='OptNo', required=True)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        try:
            otpobj = Otp.objects.get(pk=self.cleaned_data['otp_no'])
            if otpobj.phone_number == self.cleaned_data['phone_number']:
                user_number = UserNumber(user=user, phone_number=self.cleaned_data['phone_number'])
                user_number.save()
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Number is not valid')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('OTP is not valid')
```

I have added `def create()` and `def update()` method in `UserSerializer` but still it doesn't work. Please guide me for this solution and thanks in advance.